# Laravel Cors No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I've got a problem with setting up Cors on Laravel.

Here is my middleware Cors.php:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization');
}
```

I've tried within my rest client it working perfectly. I can see the headers. but when i tried to my front end (Angular) I don't get that response.

[image: Error]

Before this i use [Cors Package by barryvdh](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) but it still not support laravel 5.2

What should I add to make it working?

Comment: Are you able to paste the output of the following curl command? `curl -I -X GET http://192.168.10.10:443/v1/admin/auth/login`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It's working now. I put my middleware at wrong place.

Comment: That would explain it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel cors 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563350/laravel-cors-access-control-allow-origin-and-access-control-allow-headers)